# Powershell foreach with multiple parameter

Tags: powershell, export-csv, foreach-object

I'm trying to solve the following problem

1. I pickup latest revision from pdf files
2. Sorting this to table
3. export this table to csv

How can I use multiple parameter?

`

```
$filesToCopy = Get-ChildItem \\server\shares\drawings -Filter *.pdf |Group-Object {$_ -replace '[0ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTIJKLMNOPQRST]_(..)(?=\.)','_$1'} |ForEach-Object {
  $_.Group |Sort-Object |Select-Object -Last 1
-Recurse |`
ForEach-Object{
$Item = $_
$Type = $_.Extension
$Path = $_.FullName
$Folder = $_.PSIsContainer
$Age = $_.CreationTime

$Path | Select-Object `
    @{n="Name";e={$Item}},`
    @{n="Created";e={$Age}},`
    @{n="filePath";e={$Path}},`
    @{n="Extension";e={if($Folder){"Folder"}else{$Type}}}`
}|Export-Csv D:\test\Results.csv -NoTypeInformation }
```

`

Comment: What do you mean by "How can I use multiple parameter?" ?

Comment: You don't need a backtick to continue a pipe or a comma.

Comment: `-recurse |\`` on line 3 gives a syntax error

Answer (score 0):

I have a working example here.  I'm not sure what the goal is.  If you export to a csv, $filestocopy will just be empty.  The lone -recurse will give a syntax error.

```
echo hi | set-content file_01.pdf,file_02.pdf

$filesToCopy = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf |
Group-Object {$_ -replace '[0ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTIJKLMNOPQRST]_(..)(?=\.)','_$1'} |
ForEach-Object {
  $_.Group |Sort-Object |Select-Object -Last 1 <# -Recurse #> |
  ForEach-Object{
    $Item = $_
    $Type = $_.Extension
    $Path = $_.FullName
    $Folder = $_.PSIsContainer
    $Age = $_.CreationTime
    $Path | Select-Object @{n="Name";e={$Item}},
    @{n="Created";e={$Age}},
    @{n="filePath";e={$Path}},
    @{n="Extension";e={if($Folder){"Folder"}else{$Type}}}
  } <# |Export-Csv Results.csv -NoTypeInformation #> 
}
$filestocopy


Name        Created                filePath                       Extension
----        -------                --------                       ---------
file_01.pdf 11/25/2022 12:03:13 PM C:\users\admin\foo\file_01.pdf .pdf
file_02.pdf 11/25/2022 12:07:23 PM C:\users\admin\foo\file_02.pdf .pdf
```